# Bookmarks in Google Documents

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps Script, I wanted to create Bookmarks in Google Documents (and retrieve the links to them to use elsewhere). Went through the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/defaultservices), but could not find how to do that. Clues would help. Thanks.

Sanjay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now the required functionality is not implemented in the [Document Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_document), but there is a proper [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=803) in the issue tracker. You can star this issue to demonstrate to the GAS team that people need it and wait.